# Getting Warning for UI Layout in iOS "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have created UITableviewCell programmatically and trying to load in table view
Cell has just one imageView and UIlabel.

Although the UI looks fine , but I am seeing this warning :

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

```
 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000147f200 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f897ea24a00]   (active, names: '|':SampleTest.MemesTableViewCell:0x7f897ea2aaf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000147f2f0 UIView:0x7f897ea24a00.bottom == SampleTest.MemesTableViewCell:0x7f897ea2aaf0.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000147f570 V:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0x7f897ea18170]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f897ea24a00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000147f110 UIImageView:0x7f897ea18170.height == 80   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000147eb70 UIImageView:0x7f897ea18170.bottom == UIView:0x7f897ea24a00.bottom - 20   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000147f4d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' SampleTest.MemesTableViewCell:0x7f897ea2aaf0.height == 44   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000147f110 UIImageView:0x7f897ea18170.height == 80   (active)>
```

My Code:

```
import UIKit

class MemesTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    
    var contentHolderView : UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    private let nameLabel = UILabel()
    var memeImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        contentHolderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        addSubview(contentHolderView)

        
        contentHolderView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentHolderView.addSubview(memeImageView)
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        memeImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        memeImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            //layout contentView
            contentHolderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor,constant: 0),
            contentHolderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant: 0),
            contentHolderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor,constant: 0),
            contentHolderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor,constant: 0),
            
            memeImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentHolderView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            memeImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentHolderView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            memeImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            memeImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: memeImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentHolderView.topAnchor, constant: 12)
        ])

        
        if let lastView = contentHolderView.getTheLastAddedView() {
            
            lastView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentHolderView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        }
        
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    

}




extension UIView {
    
    func getTheLastAddedView()->UIView?{
        if let lastView = self.subviews.last{
            return lastView
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    
}
```

I like to know how can this warning be fixed?

Comment: You set the imageView's height to 80 and the tableViewCell's height is set to 44 by the table view. Did you configure dynamic height for the table view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common situation when using cells with embedded views.

As you've seen, the UI result *looks* fine -- because auto-layout will *attempt to recover by breaking constraint*, and then it re-establishes the constraint.

To get rid of the warnings, give the constraint that ends up defining the height a less-than-required priority.

So, change the end of your `setupView()` func to this:

```
    if let lastView = contentHolderView.getTheLastAddedView() {
        let c = lastView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentHolderView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        c.priority = .required - 1
        c.isActive = true
        //lastView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentHolderView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    }
    
    // this is not needed
    //self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

As a side note, a cell's subviews should not be added to, or constrained to, the cell itself. You should use the cell's `.contentView` instead:

```
    contentView.addSubview(contentHolderView)
```

and then:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        //layout contentView
        contentHolderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,constant: 0),
        contentHolderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor,constant: 0),
        contentHolderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 0),
        contentHolderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor,constant: 0),
```

Comment: I've often wondered what literally causes the inevitable "44" default.  ... `UITableViewCellContentView:0x13bd24310.height == 44`.  Even if one sets height estimate to off, you still get the 44.  It seems to be some sort of hard default in UIKit.  It's not possible to turn off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in either a cell or the cell contentView.